# Can not find symbol class Guideline

Tags: android, kotlin

I started creating a new project with the latest androidx and jetpack and databinding. Everything is going fine except when I coupled using `androidx.constraintlayout` with `databinding`. The auto-generated databinding class can't import the right package for the `Guideline` class. It is trying to import from `androidx.constraintlayout.Guideline` when in reality the class exists in `androidx.constraintlayout.Widget.Guideline`.

### Expected Behavior

AndroidStudio should import the package from `androidx.constraintlayout.Widget.Guideline` instead of `androidx.constraintlayout.Guideline` and it should compile fine.

### Current Behavior

The compiler throws the following Error:

- Cannot find symbol class Guideline

### Possible Solution

Well I could stop using Databinding with the guideline class but... Since its an auto-generated databinding class i also can't change the import package as it will be generated and overwritten again anyways at build time. I'm not sure if there is any way to enforce Android studio to import from the correct package.

Update:

I did stop using the Guidelines I had this code from another developer and realized the Guidelines were completely useless I could do without them. However, I do think this is still a bug in Android.

### Steps to Reproduce

Enable databinding for android project:

```
dataBinding {
        enabled = true
}
```

Import the following androidx libraries that I'm also using:

```
/**
 * AndroidX Libraries
 */
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

Create a Fragment with Databinding my case is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".fragments.emailConfirmation.EmailConfirmationFragment">

    <data>

        <import type="androidx.fragment.app.Fragment" />

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="android.thespikeapp.com.spike.fragments.emailConfirmation.EmailConfirmationViewModel" />
    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/image_left_guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".33" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/image_right_guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".66" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/text_left_guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".16" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/text_right_guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".84" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/horizontalGuideline"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/image_right_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/image_left_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            <!--android:src="@drawable/ic_confirm_email"-->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/confirm_email_description"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/text_right_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/text_left_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/horizontalGuideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.35" />

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryLightest"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/text_right_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/text_left_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/emailAddressEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:hint="@string/email_address"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="@={viewModel.email}"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/updateButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                android:text="@string/submit"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/text_right_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/text_left_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textInputLayout" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

Try building the app you should get the same error

### Context (Environment)

This code won't compile on the version of AndroidStudio Version 3.2.1 using kotlin 1.3.10. Also minSdkVersion is set to 21 and compileSdkVersion 28.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: If you think you have identified a bug in something related to Android, file an issue in [the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues). "It is trying to import from `androidx.constraintlayout.Guideline`" -- that is what your layout has. Beyond all of that, it is unclear what your question is.

Comment: @CommonsWare you are very right I completely missed that. As I said, I had copied the layout from another project and I guess when I used the refactor tool in AndroidStudio to refactor to androidx it converted the guideline xml tag without the Widget package. I guess if I change the tags now it should work fine!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@CommonsWare pointed out something I completely missed out that my layout file contained `androidx.constraintlayout.Guideline` instead of `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline` that fixed the problem. However, I guess when I used the refactoring tool to migrate to AndroidX it converted the Guideline tags to the initial instead of the latter. Thank you @CommonsWare for pointing out the silly mistake!

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Widget should be lowercase for all my copypastas out there <3